# Android button onclick if dialog open close it else open it

Tags: android, button, if-statement

In my app i open dialog using a button onclick, Dialog open nicely if i press again same button i want close dialog.

```
    final ImageButton topmenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    topmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Search.this);

            if(dialog!=null&&dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }else{
                   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.actionmenu);
                    TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog1);
                    text1.setText("Search");
                    dialog.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

If i press button again dialog not closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onClick of a button. Use the below code.

```
if(dialog!=null&&dialog.isShowing())
       dialog.dismiss();
    else
       dialog.show();
```

Comment: Not work i changed my post check. Dialog opening good if i press button again it not close.

Comment: Initialize this dialog in oncreate of Activity means outside of onclick listener..  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Search.this);dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); dialog.setContentView(R.layout.actionmenu);

Answer (score 0):

Dialog has an isShowing() method that should return if the dialog is currently visible. So you can use that to see if a dialog is showing and hide it with dismissDialog().

Comment: Not work i changed my post check again. Dialog opening good if i press button again it not close.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Button topmenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu);
topmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

if(dialog!=null&&dialog.isShowing()){
dialog.dismiss();
}else{
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.change_password);
TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog1);
text1.setText("Search");
dialog.show();
}

}
});

}


}
```

It Works...
The problem with your code may be its not in on create method nor been initialised in on create..first do initialisation in on create and then declare it.

Comment: Should format code and explain why it works or why code in question failed.